# Hovering over a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in a WinForms app in Windows 11 turns cell black (OK in Windows 10)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

When we run our application on Windows 11 the DataGridView control seems to act differently. Hovering over a cell in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn turns the cell black making any text in that cell  unreadable (see image). Windows 10 is OK.
[Screenshot of datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSB1f.png)

Any ideas why this control acts differently in Windows 11. And if so, is it permanent? I *could* add some code in to try and fix this, but so far my efforts (below) have not worked.

```
    private void DataGridView_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 255);
        }
    }

    private void DataGridView_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLight;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect that there is an issue with theme on the Win11 machine in regards to the color retrieved for ComboBoxState.Hot.  Assuming you have the default `ComboBoxColumn.FlatStyle` property of `System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Standard`, try setting that property to `System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat`.

Comment: Yes, that has fixed the problem. Many thanks. The flat style is perhaps more modern, also!

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer already given by @TnTinMn in the question's comments above, you could fix this for all DataGridViewComboBoxColumn columns in your application by implementing a custom DataGridView control and overriding the OnColumnAdded method:

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnColumnAdded(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn && comboColumn.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Standard)
        {
            comboColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        }
        base.OnColumnAdded(e);
    }
}
```